# Android drawable canvas - Change border design and color

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I am new at Canvas and drawing in Android and I just took the code [from this website](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/06/drawing-example-in-android.html) I managed to tweak it however, I am finding it difficult to change the border style and the border color.

I want the border to just be a simple black square border, no fancy waves and color spectrums.

This is the code in the onCreate function, I already managed to minimize the wavyness of the border but there's still tiny bumps and turns.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     float[] outerR = new float[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

     RectF inset = new RectF(6, 6, 6, 6);
     float[] innerR = new float[] { 12, 12, 0, 0, 12, 12, 0, 0 };

     mDrawables = new ShapeDrawable[2];

     mDrawables[0] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, inset, null));
     //mDrawables[0].getPaint().setShader(makeSweep());

     mDrawables[1] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, inset, innerR));
     //mDrawables[1].getPaint().setShader(makeLinear());

     PathEffect mPathEffect1 = new DiscretePathEffect(1, 1);
     PathEffect mPathEffect2 = new CornerPathEffect(1);

     mDrawables[0].getPaint().setPathEffect(new ComposePathEffect(mPathEffect2, mPathEffect1));
     RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myDrawing);
     layout.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawables[0]);
     activity = this; 


     //mView = new DrawingView(this);
     mView = new SignatureView(activity, null);

     layout.addView(mView, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     init();

     mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
     mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
 }
```

Sorry I know this may turn out to be a simple task but I'm completely stumped.

EDIT - Okay I managed to make it plain black, I just removed the mDrawables[0/1].getPaint() lines and it turned to black, my only problem right now is to make it perfectly straight.

Comment: no apologies needed, you have researched, tweaked the code, shown us what you have done and are quite specific of the outcome you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

For the color of the border, comment out the following lines:
`mDrawables[0].getPaint().setShader(makeSweep());` and `mDrawables[1].getPaint().setShader(makeLinear());`

After that, the problem is the DiscretePathEffect. Change that line of code to:
`PathEffect mPathEffect1 = new DiscretePathEffect(1, 0);`

Apparently, the two arguments for the DiscretePathEffect determine how "squiggly" the line gets.